# Extending pagerank algorithm

Tags: algorithm, probability, pagerank

We know page rank algorithm is the random surfer, which can browse hyperlinks or do random teleports. Lets imagine a scenario where we want to extend this where consider the option for the random surfer to use a "back button of the browser" which takes him to the back page (i.e page where he came from. However, the random surfer is not allowed to use this option recursively. So, once he used back button he has to either click a link or teleport to new page. Furthermore, we consider back button to be used with certain probability 'p'.

Note: we have to restrict user not to use back button recursively.

I was wondering how can we extend the existing page rank algorithm where a user can go from one page to next page with probability (1/number of outlinks) or teleport with probability alpha.

Any idea or link for further reading would be appreciated. I tried to google "pagerank with backlink" but couldn't find good information.

Answer (score 0):

PageRank relies on links between pages. Clicking on the back button is not creating a link between pages. So if you go from page A to page B, there isn't necessarily a link from B to A.

You could add them to your graph or adjust the probability if they already exist and re-run PageRank.